# How to find an organization that offers semi-guided tours?

Tags: tours, guides

I am looking for an organization that offers tours, that are close to an individual travel experience.

The organization should:
 + organize the lodging
 
 + organize the travel from site to site
 
 + be able to provide tips and help
 + maybe offer some guided elements.

- But the tour should have plenty of time for individual exploring
- and no tourist style sight-seeing marathons

The closest I've found to this is: [Shoestring Travel](http://shoestring.com/). They have trips through various countries in various difficulties (light travel <-> difficult journey). Their tours take you to multiple destinations and an english-speaking, local guide travels with the group. Unfortunately my travel time and their tours don't match.

**Are there (other) organizations or companies that offer such semi-guided tours? Or how can I find them?**
(Googling doesn't help here as there are far to many "tourist style" travel companies that appear for the relevant search terms.)

Comment: Do you have a region in mind? Eg. Europe, Africa? Your question is quite broad at present, and as per the [faq], the more detail the better.

Comment: Also at present you're essentially asking for a list of companies, which again, falls foul of the [faq] which says not to do this.  If you could reword your question, that might be better - as it stands it risks close votes :/

Comment: Thanks. I had India or South America in mind, but since the organization I found offers tours all over the globe, I assumed others might as well. Of course that doesn't have to be the fact.

Comment: Normally a 'guided tour' implies that you travel with a guide. These will either happen in large groups, or be extremely expensive (because the cost of the guide is shared between only a few people). If you just mean that someone organizes the itinerary and does the booking for you, that's different.

Comment: @DJClayworth I think she means they take you from place to place (city) but then you're left alone during the day to do what you want.  Fairly rare though, in my experience.

Comment: @Mark: Yes, either that or a tour with some guided elements but also a fair amount of "beeing left alone to explore".

Answer (score 6):

I think that there are a multitude of organisations offering this. It is what old-fashioned travel agents do these days. With so many different travel resources, like travel.se, tripadvisor, airbnb, etc doing it all yourself is the adagium these days.
Just to survive city center based travel agents aim at individual package journeys. 
I know at least two organisations ([Riksja travel](http://www.riksjatravel.nl/)  and [Joker travel](http://www.joker.be/), that seems to offer what you want. Both websites are in Dutch only, sort of proving that these type of organizations aim at only a select geographical region.

I am not aware of the situation in Germany regarding travel agents, but for individual travel packages I visit different travel agents in the city center. My favorite outdoor store in Germany [Globetrotter](http://www.globetrotter.de/), seems to have a [travelshop](http://www.reiseland-globetrotter.de/). I would assume that, given the gear they sell, they would also offer individual travel packages.